# Does ‘git push’ create a new SSH session?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, git, heroku

I've set up a new EC2 instance with Heroku-like deploy. I followed this article cuppster.com/2011/05/12/diy-node-js-server-on-amazon-ec2/. My problem is... If I push to the server several times, CPU jumps to 90%. I was wondering, what does it cause?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

git push does open a new SSH session, but i think your CPU usage might actually be disk I/O related rather than network related. unless your local machine's got a silly SSL install, there's no reason for the CPU usage to jump like that.

try first adding an entry to your /etc/hosts file for your EC2 instance (with the hostname you're using to connect) as it's possible (but unlikely) it's freaking out on an rDNS lookup, and then try watching your disk i/o as you make the connection.